# Facebook (Meta) Graph API how to get the Name of the FB User who created a comment or post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Currently when running [https://graph.facebook.com/{myPageId}?fields=posts{id,created_time,message,child_attachments,from,full_picture,attachments{url},likes,reactions,comments{created_time,from,id,message,comments{created_time,from,id,message}}}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7BmyPageId%7D?fields=posts%7Bid,created_time,message,child_attachments,from,full_picture,attachments%7Burl%7D,likes,reactions,comments%7Bcreated_time,from,id,message,comments%7Bcreated_time,from,id,message%7D%7D%7D)

I get the following result>

```
{
"posts": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "commentId",
        "created_time": "2022-05-11T22:51:03+0000",
        "from": {
          "name": "some name",
          "id": "userId"
        }, 
        "message": "test message1"
      },
      {
        "id": "commentId2",
        "created_time": "2022-05-11T22:51:03+0000", 
        "message": "test message2"     
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "beforecursor",
        "after": "aftercursor"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "postId"
}
```

I'm only getting the "from" information from my own FB user and from the Page's user that I have access to but any other comment by anybody else I only get the message, the Id and the created time. I need the From so I can get the name to create a contact on my system so I can associate cases to that User.
How can I solve this?

Comment: What type of access token are you using - admin user token, or a page token?

Comment: @CBroe Using Page Access Token since the Admin User Token doesn't even get me the list of comments.